# How to configure a Android Multi Module APP to work with IBM Mobile Foudation Platfom 8.0's AppAuthenticity

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, authenticity

We had a Android app that had work fine with IBM Mobile Foudation Platform 8.0' AppAuthenticity. So we had to split the app into multiple android modules, and AppAuthenticity has not work since.
When trying to login with AppAuthenticity  enabled there is no response, ie the success or error callbacks are never fired.

https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/authentication-and-security/application-authenticity/

IBM MFP Server Version: 8.0.2019022810.
IBM MFP Android SDK Version: 8.0.+ 
Gradle build tool : 3.1.1
Gradle 4.4
The problem happens with debug and release apks.

```
Log.d("TAG", "loginMobileFirst init"); // This appears in logcat

String securityCheckName = CaixaSecurityCheckChallengeHandler.SECURITY_CHECK_NAME;

WLAuthorizationManager.getInstance()
                      .login(securityCheckName, this.getCredencial(),
            new WLLoginResponseListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    Log.d(TAG, "loginMobileFirst Success"); // This never appears in logcat
                    setLogged(true);
                    callBack.onSuccess(null);

                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(WLFailResponse wlFailResponse) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "loginMobileFirst Failure"); // This never appears in logcat
                    Log.d(TAG, "Erro no login: " + wlFailResponse.getErrorMsg());
                    callBack.onError(context.getString(R.string.api_error_sistema_indisponivel));
                }
            });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved deleting the directory app/src/main/jniLibs. I believe that directory was included in a old version of IBM MFP (7.1)

Thank you, Folks!

Answer (score 0):

MobileFirst does not yet support app modules of Android. Please create a single apk for your app until this is supported.

Please open a request for enhancement at https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/execute?use_case=changeRequestLanding&BRAND_ID=0&PROD_ID=702&x=17&y=6